# Choosing Desktop Environments in linux and Linux Distros

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am a newbie to the linux world and while researching on best distro for linux to use, I came to know that we can install and switch DEs. For eg: If I use Ubuntu (unity) and say if I install lubuntu DE, gnome DE via terminal and then start using it. My question now is that, Does the above example EQUAL TO installing lubuntu or gnome manually in the first place instead of Ubuntu unity version ? Or Does it only change the appearance?

I am very much confused after searching and researching on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu and other Ubuntu derivatives are indeed mostly Ubuntu with a specific DE setup as default. You can get some goodies (themes, etc...) and some specific applications installed by default, but functionally there is nothing that you cannot obtain by installing the adequate packages (DE and other apps) from the Ubuntu repositories.